# WPF - Music visualization

Tags: wpf, visualization, audio-player

I'm working on an audio player for my school project. One of the requirements is, that it must have some sort of music visualization(osciloscope, spectrum analyzer, spectrogram). I found the [WPFSVL](http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/) but can't get it to work, because i already have the playback and all the other  stuff implemented with the [IrrKlang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) library (doesn't have methods for acquiring FFT data).

So in a nutshell, what i want is somesort of music visualization control without the playback.

p.s. I've looked at the samples of the WPFSVL library. I think I could use the NAudio sample to get the spectrum analyzer control , but it's a little difficult to understand what's going on there.

Comment: Here [http://inchoatethoughts.com/a-wpf-spectrum-analyzer-for-audio-visualization-c-part-2-the-wpfening] is article on WPFSVL Spectrum Analyzer. Hope you get some idea.

Comment: I assume you are required to build a visualizer based on the audio that is playing. If so, you need to be able to get audio spectrum data. It sounds like IrrKlang doesn't provide the data you need. I would switch to a library that does. If, however, your visualization doesn't need to be based on the audio, you can use WPFSVL and just feed it randomly generated FFT data.

Comment: Yes I agree, that is why I wanted to use the NAudio sample. The problem is, the player is nearly finished, so I do not want to change everything because of this. I only need to know if it would be possible to visualize music without playing its sound, so I would have IrrKlang take care of the playback and NAudio would handle the visualization. And yes, I would prefer it, if the visualization was based on the current playing audio.

Comment: @RunoTheDog You might be able to have NAudio play the same file that IrrKrlang is playing - just mute the NAudio channel and use it for spectrum analysis only. But trying to keep IrrKlang and NAudio in sync would probably be more work than just switching to NAudio completely.

Comment: Hey, @Neeraj, you should post your comment as an answer. I that is the response to the problem.